# Error: Declaration of MyClass::start_lvl() should be compatible with that of Walker_Nav_Menu::start_lvl()

Tags: menus, errors, compatibility

I'm currently working on a WordPress site and whenever in the admin I go the Appearance > Menus page I get the following error:

> ErrorException: Runtime Notice: Declaration of Walker_Nav_Menu_Edit::start_lvl() should be compatible with that of Walker_Nav_Menu::start_lvl() in wp-admin/includes/nav-menu.php line 203

It seems like some sort of PHP compatibility issue. I'm running PHP 5.3.10 on my local dev machine.

What would be the best way to remedy this problem?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

From `class Walker_Nav_Menu`:

```
function start_lvl( &$output, $depth = 0, $args = array() )
```

Your child class *must* use the same signature: three arguments, the first one passed by reference. Every difference will raise the error you got.

Note that `$args` defaults to an empty array, but you get an instance of `stdClass`, not an array. This is WordPress.

Comment: I know. It's a WordPress class, it's not for me to change. My question is what's the best way to work around the problem (preferably without meddling with WP's internals)...

Comment: You are not being told to meddle with WordPress core. You need to alter the way you define your method in your extended class to match the way WordPress does it in the original class.

Comment: Got it. The error was throwing me off. It gave me the impression the problem was in WP core but it's referring to the definition of the signature, not where the problem occurred.

Answer (score 18):

### From class `Walker_Nav_Menu` replace this lines

```
function start_el(&$output, $category, $depth, $args) {
```

to

```
function start_el(&$output, $category, $depth = 0, $args = array(), $current_object_id = 0) {
```

---

```
function end_lvl(&$output, $depth, $args) {
```

to

```
function end_lvl(&$output, $depth = 0, $args = array()) {
```

---

```
function start_lvl(&$output, $depth, $args) {
```

to

```
function start_lvl(&$output, $depth = 0, $args = array()) {
```

---

```
function end_el(&$output, $category, $depth, $args) {
```

to

```
function end_el(&$output, $category, $depth = 0, $args = array()) {
```

Comment: Can you also explain how it works instead of just adding the code and how is it different from the accepted answer

Comment: Yes; The answer is updated in 2015, and it does not work on the new version of Wordpress [link](https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/master/wp-includes/class-wp-walker.php)

Comment: Yes, so explanation of the answer would be awesome.

Comment: This saved my ass, definitely the correct answer if you have 4 error messages, for function start_el, function end_el, function start_lvl, function end_lvl

Comment: Where or how we go to the  class Walker_Nav_Menu??? I do not know how or where It is selected!!!!!

Answer (score 0):

This was the same in my case. You get old nav menu walker codes, and it says what you should do when you turn on wp_debug(true)

**Menu_Frontend::start_lvl(&$output, $depth) should be compatible with Walker_Nav_Menu::start_lvl(&$output, $depth = 0, $args = NULL) in C:\xampp\htdocs\shopnet\wp-content\themes\Viteeo\hades_framework\helper\megamenu.php on line 314**

As you can see you need to change some code line what PHP refers to you. In above error notice you should replace start_lvl(&$output, $depth) with start_lvl(&$output, $depth = 0, $args = NULL)
so other processes are the same. But don't forget to write function opening tag { at the end, like this NULL) {